# Datatable binds to XML after the load need a fix

Tags: xml, vb.net, datatable

I have a Datatable in which XML gets loaded. For some reason when I close XML reader it still binds the data.... and I am unable to manipulate data anymore I am getting a DBnull to String error because some cells are empty. However, if I add more rows manually I can manipulate data with no issues(empty cells). Only rows that get loaded from XML get the error. I don't have any settings set to bind data to datatable and I tried to set everything to false after XML gets loaded however issue still exists. From what I read so far DBnull is an error which occurs when writing an empty value to database.... in this case XML I would think. I am NOT sure why it tries to write any value at all since XML supposed to be loaded in datatable and closed after. All values should be manipulated from the APP and in no way linked to xml after loading. I think Table does it automatically after loading binds to XML and I am not able to find a solution at this moment.
Please advise or let me know if I missed anything.

```
Dim xmlFile As XmlReader
        xmlFile = XmlReader.Create("FILE.xml", New XmlReaderSettings())
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        ds.ReadXml(xmlFile)
        Dim i As Integer

        Dim clm1 As String = "1"


        For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            If ds.Tables(0).Columns.Contains(clm1) = False Then
                Continue For
            ElseIf ds.Tables(0).Columns.Contains(clm1) = True Then
                DataTable_d.Item(clm1, rowIndex:=i).Value = (ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(clm1))
            End If
    Next

    xmlFile.Close()
```

Comment: please add your source code because mydataset.readxml show not this behaviour.

Comment: You must add the code show how DataTable is filled from the XML file. Show the code that is causing the error. Show the code you use to add rows manually to the DataTable.

Comment: Hello I added the part of code. Full code is very extensive since there is a lot of columns. Errors will come in multiple places since data grid has multiple functions all refer to DBnull. It is possible that data set is the issue as well now when I think about it?